# Need to find out last 15 days record (each day which record are last inserted in my table )

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Need Help
Lets say--I have a staging table, everyday record are inserted, there is column is T_CREATED, This column has date (ddmmyyy hh24miss) example “12/16/2014 11:47:14 AM”
My scenario was, I need to find out when is last record last 15 days. Which means each day(in 24 hr) which record are last inserted
Can I get suggestion here?
I know I have to use MAX(T_CREATED) but could not figure it out.
Thanks 
Sohel

Comment: if anyone has any question regarding this, please ask me-Thanks

Comment: @Sohel I might be mistaken but I don't think `16` is a month?

Comment: -- last 15 days example if I do SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(T_CREATED,'MMDDYYYY HH24MISS) FROM account_customer WHERE T_CREATED ='15-SEP-2016'. IT will give me last row inserted in that table with timestamp right? what I want same thing last 15 days(not month).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax in Oracle, this code will return the latest T_CREATED for each day.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT MAX(obj_ID) AS MaxID, CONVERT(DATE, T_CREATED) AS [Date]
FROM source_tbl
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, T_CREATED) > CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, T_CREATED)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, T_CREATED) DESC

-- Oracle
SELECT MAX(T_CREATED) AS MaxID, TRUNC(T_CREATED) AS [Date]
FROM source_tbl
WHERE TRUNC(T_CREATED) > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15)
GROUP BY TRUNC(T_CREATED)
ORDER BY TRUNC(T_CREATED) DESC
```

Comment: Anytime dude!! Cheers